# How to drop superuser of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, command-line

[image]

I want to delete the user Mark but every time when I use the drop user Mark; command i get this message:
[image]

or if i try to drop the role i get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?
How do I fix this?

Comment: Linux is case-sensitive

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
drop user "Mark";
```

As role name `Mark` is not in small case. In postgres if identifiers are not in small case then it must be surrounded by `"`.